# Cable that supports stereo line in for the 30 pin connector on old iPhones/iPods?

Tags: iphone, audio, ipod, lightning

According to http://pinouts.ru/CellularPhones-A-N/iPhone_connector_pinout.shtml two of the pins in Apple's 30 pin connector are dedicated to *line in*. I have spent days looking for a cable with line in capabilities (because I want to record **stereo** line in, the headphone jack is **mono** and is not line level) but they are nowhere to be found. I can only find http://line6.com/sonicport-audio-interface/sonicport/ and similar that are way to bulky and unnecessary expensive for my purpose.

Do I suck at Google? Does it exist simple 30-pin cables with support for line in? If not, why? The reason I ask the last two questions is that if such a cable doesn't exist my plan is to find someone in a music shop or similar and ask them if they cold make/solder such a cable for me.

Comment: The sonicport is also only mono [see iRig answer/comments below] - I really think there must be some solid reason why a stereo variant is so rare.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this might be it:
http://www.ikmultimedia.com/mobile/products/irighd/
But it's not cheap.

Comment: ...nor is it stereo. The only stereo iRig is the [iMic Field](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/irigmicfield) The new [iRig pro Duo](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/products/irigproduo) is 'dual channel' - though I'm not sure whether that is dual mono or can be summed to stereo. I guess you could be fairly sure, though, that if IK don't make one, there's a good reason.

Comment: You're right, now that I went back and re-read the page, they don't mention stereo anywhere. I took it for granted that it would be stereo since I can't imagine anyone paying $$ for a mono recorder. But I'm not really an audio person so I guess that was a bad assumption.

Comment: Furthermore, it is not a simple cable but a whole audio interface with AD-converter and more. I am happy to use the built in (?) AD-converter to save space.